# quickly switching to a buffer with a particular file name/mode

Tags: buffers

G'day!  it's my "learn some more Elisp" day.

I'm trying to make a shortcut that opens my main org file.
I've made it this far

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c h") 'switch-to-most-recent-org-file)

(defun switch-to-most-recent-org-file ()
  (interactive)
  (message "hi"))
```

Instead of `(message "hi")`,  I want emacs to switch to the .org file
in the *Buffer List*.  Sometimes there will be multiple .org files in
the *Buffer List*, in that case go for the one at the top.

Comment: (global-set-key (kbd "C-c h") 'switch-to-most-recent-org-file)

(defun switch-to-most-recent-org-file ()
  (interactive)
  (message "hi"))

Comment: Yes, I read that the first time.  Very cheeky.  What have you
tried in place of `(message "hi")`?  If the answer is "I tried X,
Y, and Z, but I'm stuck," then say so so people can help.  If the
answer is "nothing," however, please do some basic background
research before posting a question.  Start with the elisp manual
nodes
on
[Switching to a Buffer in a Window](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Switching-Buffers.html)
and [The Buffer List](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-List.html).  I found these nodes via google searches.

Comment: I come here for help with code and I go away with life advice :)

Comment: Here is something to get you started.  If the `buffer-list` is not being processed with `mapc` in the right order, then you can reverse the order with `(nreverse (buffer-list))` -- If you want the second to the most recent assuming that you are already in an `org-mode` buffer, then you'll need to tweak the example:  `(let (found) (catch 'done (mapc (lambda (x) (when (with-current-buffer x (eq major-mode 'org-mode)) (switch-to-buffer x) (setq found t) (throw 'done nil))) (buffer-list)) (unless found (message "not found"))))`  I'm not writing an answer, because I don't have much free time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @lawlist works for me.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c h") 'switch-to-most-recent-org-file)

(defun switch-to-most-recent-org-file ()
  (interactive)
  (let (found)
    (catch 'done
      (mapc (lambda (x)
              (when (with-current-buffer x (eq major-mode 'org-mode))
                (switch-to-buffer x)
                (setq found t)
                (throw 'done nil)))
            (buffer-list))
      (unless found (message "not found")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the file you want to switch to might not be in the buffer-list.
(Very early in the morning after a reboot)

So I find the answer mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558019/shortcut-to-open-a-specific-file-in-emacs
useful.

> Personally I prefer to use emacs registers to store
> files which I use often. I would store '~/.emacs' in a register:
>
> (set-register ?e (cons 'file "~/.emacs"))
>
> and open it with  C-x r j e