# Switch to most recent buffer in a given mode

Tags: buffers, major-mode

I am trying to create a function that switches to the most recent buffer in major mode `major-mode`. An [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/35804/32089) to a related [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35793/quickly-switching-to-a-buffer-with-a-particular-file-name-mode) supplies a function that should require the smallest of tweaks to serve my purpose, but I can't make it work. Here is the original function in that answer:

```el
(defun switch-to-most-recent-org-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let (found)
    (catch 'done
      (mapc (lambda (x)
              (when (with-current-buffer x (eq major-mode 'org-mode))
                (switch-to-buffer x)
                (setq found t)
                (throw 'done nil)))
            (buffer-list))
      (unless found (message "not found")))))
```

I thought I could just replace the first and sixth lines, respectively, with

```
(defun switch-to-most-recent-buffer-in-mode (major-mode)
```

and

```
              (when (with-current-buffer x (eq major-mode major-mode))
```

Which gives me this:

```el
(defun switch-to-most-recent-buffer-in-mode (major-mode)
  (interactive)
  (let (found)
    (catch 'done
      (mapc (lambda (x)
              (when (with-current-buffer x (eq major-mode major-mode))
                (switch-to-buffer x)
                (setq found t)
                (throw 'done nil)))
            (buffer-list))
      (unless found (message "not found")))))
```

but it doesn't work: while the original function switches to my most recent org buffer, evaluating `(switch-to-most-recent-buffer-in-mode org-mode)` returns a "not found" message. It seems I am failing to grasp something very basic about Elisp, so please excuse my ignorance: I'm not a programmer and am new to Emacs.

--

[edited to add:] The amended code below works (taken from phils's answer).

```
(defun switch-to-most-recent-buffer-in-mode (mode)
  (interactive "C")
  (let (found)
    (catch 'done
      (mapc (lambda (x)
              (when (with-current-buffer x (eq major-mode mode))
                (switch-to-buffer x)
                (setq found t)
                (throw 'done nil)))
            (buffer-list))
      (unless found (message "not found")))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your changes:

> ```el
> (defun switch-to-most-recent-buffer-in-mode (major-mode)
>   (interactive)
> ```

The first problem is that you used the name of a standard variable for your argument, which means that the real `major-mode` is shadowed by whatever you pass to your function.  You should rename that to something else (`mode` would be safe).

The second problem is with the `interactive` form, which tells Emacs how to obtain the function arguments interactively (e.g. if called with `M-x` or by a key binding).  By adding a required argument, but not changing the `interactive` spec, this command now won't work interactively.

You could make that `(interactive "C")` to read a command symbol (which will include all modes).

Your next change is:

> ```el
> (when (with-current-buffer x (eq major-mode major-mode))
> ```

That `(eq major-mode major-mode)` will hopefully look pretty dodgy to you upon review.  It is guaranteed to be true.

You have run headlong into the first problem here -- you are trying to compare the standard variable `major-mode` with the argument you added of the exact same name, which obviously can't work.

Take note that even if the function wasn't *directly* using the standard variable, name clashes are often unsafe (whether and how depends on the specifics, though).  It's best to stick to un-hyphenated single word names for function arguments, as the *vast* majority of global variables are hyphenated.

Finally, you're not calling your function correctly.

> ```el
> (switch-to-most-recent-buffer-in-mode org-mode)
> ```

You are trying to evaluate the variable `org-mode` and pass its value to the function.

The value of `major-mode` (the standard variable, with which you will later be comparing the argument you've passed) is a *symbol*, so you need to quote the argument to prevent it from being evaluated, so that you are passing the *symbol* `org-mode`:

```el
(switch-to-most-recent-buffer-in-mode 'org-mode)
```

> returns a "not found" message.

I would actually have expected either an error (because `org-mode` isn't normally a valid variable to evaluate in your call), or for it to unconditionally select the first buffer (because `(eq major-mode major-mode)` is always true), so I'm not sure whether you were testing what you've described; but hopefully these pointers are sufficient in any case.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I amended the code to reflect your suggests, but I'm still getting a "not found" message. I've updated my question with the code I used.

Comment: Your new problem is `(eq major-mode 'mode)` which is another quoting problem -- this time you're quoting something which *shouldn't* be quoted.  Here `mode` is a variable and you want it to be evaluated so that you are comparing the value of that variable with the value of the `major-mode` variable.  I.e. If the value of `major-mode` is `org-mode` and the value of `mode` is also `org-mode` then your current code is false because the two symbols `org-mode` and `mode` are not the same thing.

Comment: Symbols and Quoting can be difficult ideas to get to grips with, and a full understanding requires you to know the difference between the `read` and `eval` phases of lisp execution, which is a bit of a deep-dive if you're new to the language.  I recommend doing some research about these topics, though -- it might not all make sense, but even a basic understanding will help a lot.

Comment: Thanks again, and sorry for misreading your original answer, which was clear enough. Unfortunately it still returns "not found".

Comment: Mmh, I take back what I said. It does work. (I had accidentally closed the buffer, which was the only buffer in the particular major mode I tried the command with.) Thanks!

Comment: The shortest version is that the quote `'` says "don't *evaluate* the thing being quoted".  So `mode` evaluates to the value of the variable `mode` (in your case the value is a symbol `org-mode`), whereas `'mode` evaluates to just itself -- the symbol `mode`.

Comment: (Thanks for the additional comments. I see them only now.)